Vite manifest not found Exception
My application was working normally until yesterday morning. Since this morning I have encountered this problem and unfortunately all my attempts to resolve it have yielded nothing.
My laravel version is 11.12.0
C:\LARAVEL PROJECT\fowambe1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Vite.php :728
{
    $path = $this->manifestPath($buildDirectory);

    if (! isset(static::$manifests[$path])) {
        if (! is_file($path)) {
            throw new ViteManifestNotFoundException("Vite manifest not found at: $path");
        }

        static::$manifests[$path] = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
    }

    return static::$manifests[$path];
}

/**
 * Get the path to the manifest file for the given build directory.
 *

I tried with npm install and npm run build
I have Following results
The specified path was not found
despite this, I also notice the absence of the public/build directory and all my attempts to obtain this directory yield nothing.

Please i need help

This question is similar to: Vite manifest not found. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
